# Getting @attributes from JSON file with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, attributes

So I have a JSON file, which is basically an ATOM XML encoded into JSON with PHP, each entry looks like this:

```
{
    id: "info:fedora/demo:SmileyBucket/RELS-EXT/2008-07-02T05:09:42.937Z",
    title: "RELS-EXT.0",
    updated: "2008-07-02T05:09:42.937Z",
    category: [
        {
            @attributes: {
                term: "info:fedora/fedora-system:FedoraRELSExt-1.0",
                scheme: "info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#formatURI"
            }
        },
        {
            @attributes: {
                term: "RDF Statements about this object",
                scheme: "info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#label"
            }
        },
        {
            @attributes: {
                term: "500",
                scheme: "info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#length"
            }
        }
    ],
    content: {
        @attributes: {
            type: "application/rdf+xml"
        }
    }
},
```

I can get all the data except the things that are in @attributes.
Here is a snippet of my jQuery:

```
$("#content-pane").text("ID: " +json.id);
$("#content-pane").append("<br/> Title: " +json.title);
$("#content-pane").append("<br/> Attributes: " +json.entry[5].content.toString());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access properties using a key:

```
var attributes = json.category[0]["@attributes"];
```

One other note: Proper JSON has to have the key names in double quotes (please note there's a difference between a JSON as data interchange format, and defining an object in script). If you define an object in script using JSON syntax, you will need to quote key names that have illegal characters (such as @).

Here's a Fiddle showing a working sample. http://jsfiddle.net/4YhTk/3/

Comment: yea the quotes are the in the original file, they disappeared because  of a chrome extension when copy/pasting